# npm publish 429 Too Many Requests

Tags: npm, npm-publish

I am trying to npm publish my package https://github.com/kofifus/HyperappComponent

In windows cmd I cloned the package, login to npm then try `npm publish`

I get:

```
C:\Temp\HyperappComponent>npm publish
npm notice
npm notice package: hyperappcomponent@0.1.0
npm notice === Tarball Contents ===
npm notice 11.6kB LICENSE
npm notice 3.7kB  index.js
npm notice 235B   package.json
npm notice 4.2kB  README.md
npm notice === Tarball Details ===
npm notice name:          hyperappcomponent
npm notice version:       0.1.0
npm notice package size:  6.8 kB
npm notice unpacked size: 19.7 kB
npm notice shasum:        48dab5ae762c43ae9afe3a24df79edf07942082c
npm notice integrity:     sha512-Xgf3YoCRPd68v[...]eLWhg8GH2wqWg==
npm notice total files:   4
npm notice
npm ERR! code E429
npm ERR! 429 Too Many Requests - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/hyperappcomponent
```

What is wrong here ?

Comment: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/836#issuecomment-589404272

Comment: @morganney are you saying it's a temporary outage ? I've been trying for a week and so no outage reports for npm online

Comment: I’m saying it could be something similar. A proxy like CF could be interpreting the HTTP spec in a way that forbids the request from `npm` due to the `Referer` header it sends. I’m not sure if npm is still using `install` as the value but if I were you I would check.

Comment: What version of npm are you using? https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/930

Comment: @morganney indeed the problem was my version was too old, if you want to post an answer I'll mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your `npm` version to one that uses a version of `npm-registry-fetch` >= 8.0.0. The reason being, that version of `npm-registry-fetch` [removes the use of a non-standard `Referer` header value](https://github.com/npm/npm-registry-fetch/commit/ebddbe78a5f67118c1f7af2e02c8a22bcaf9e850) while making requests that certain [proxies like CloudFare may deem as a violation of the HTTP spec](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/836#issuecomment-589404272), and thus block based on their own custom heuristic.

Looks like versions of `npm` >= 7.0.0 [have the necessary dependency on `npm-registry-fetch`](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/v7.0.0/package.json#L89).

In this case, [according to Roy Fielding](https://github.com/httpwg/http-core/issues/321#issuecomment-590448596):

> Instead, npm sent a special value without a special scheme, and Cloudflare marked that for rate limiting based on incorrect assumptions of bad behavior rather than the actual specification. Excuses happen.

Answer (score 6):

You need to `npm login` first.

The error (429 Too Many Requests) is misleading.

Comment: This solved the issue for me. Very misleading error.